# Gitlab CI: develop gets tested, version updated and pushed to master; but rebase to develop tests again

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Question in short: I run all test on **develop** how can I prevent them on a rebase from **master** done by the CI user?

I have a quite common CI approach configured in GitLab:

1. every push to **develop** should be tested
2. on test success: deploy to **master**
3. every deployment to **master** decides depending on the commit log if a new SemVer is necessary. If that is the case some local version files get changed, committed and the release is tagged. Additional **develop** gets rebased to **master** (so that the version file changes get promoted there)

That looks like this in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
- test
- pushToMaster
- tagNewVersion
- deploy

test:
  stage: test
  only:
  - develop
  except:
    variables:
    - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /[TASK] Releasing/

pushToMaster:
  stage: pushToMaster
  only:
  - develop

tagNewVersion:
  stage: tagNewVersion
  only:
  - master
```

Now a commit to develop creates this jobs:

1. develop "my new code" => test (✓) => pushToMaster (✓)
2. master "my new code" => tagNewVersion (✓)
3. x.y.z "[TASK] Releasing my project version x.y.z" => tagNewVersion (✓)
4. develop "[TASK] Releasing my project version x.y.z" => test (✓) => pushToMaster (✓, nothing to do)

My aim is to prevent the 4th job. I thought the except:variables for job test would do the trick, but to no avail. A `[skip-ci]` in the commit won't work as the tagged version needs a CI run for deployment. Are there any other options? Like a special condition depending on the user (real human vs. specific CI account). I couldn't find any but can't think that this is so uncommon..

Comment: I think you have to escape the brackets: `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[TASK\] Releasing/`

Comment: Your sir deserve a handshake before I use my hand for the obligatory facepalm. Upgrading that comment to an answer will result in an accepted answer ofc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets are reserved characters in a regular expression and must therefore be escaped.

So your `except` must become:

```
except:
  variables:
  - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[TASK\] Releasing/
```